# What are these on power supply cables?

Tags: power-supply, cables

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Name of this component](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/45739/name-of-this-component)

I've noticed that on many home electronics there are sometimes power supplies that have a bulky unit attached to the cable. I don't even know what these are called to be able to search for them.

What are these called?
What purpose are these for and why do some gadgets have them and other not?

Below are are some examples highlighted in red

[image]
[image]

Comment: Indeed, identical question, but with no practical way for someone with the thing itself in hand and a photograph of it, to be able to find it.  Maybe a visual search feature, or photo guide to parts and gadgets?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These "Common mode chokes" are better described as **ferrite cable cores**.
**Ferrite beads**  are more commonly used with single wire. Even though the cores have  evolved into larger cores one still sees the old desscription as "beads".

> These are the most widely used materials in EMI solutions.

They serve to reduce egress as well as ingress on cables to isolate high frequency noise from interference.  Since cables contain both paths the net current is zero for DC and low frequncy but at high frequency the common mode impedance of the cable is increased much higher than the differential impedance which is mostly unaffected. For this reason they are mandatory on all VGA video cables in order to pass the FCC/CE standard noise emission tests and used on SMPS power supply charger cables to reduce (but not eliminate) common mode hum causing interference with high impedance inputs. (mics)

Ferrite beads come in many different forumations with relative permeability ranging from 100 to 10k using Zn, Mg, & Fe oxides that can be formulated to be high Q low loss (more like ideal inductors) or very lossy high impedance 1~5k) broad spectrum or low u, high current or microwave absorbers from radar.

Answer (score 5):

They [are](http://computer.howstuffworks.com/question352.htm) [ferrite beads](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ferrite_bead), and are used to suppress noise from electronic circuits - in this case, they prevent the cable from acting as an antenna (both as an unintentional transmitter of high-frequency noise and as a receiver of noise from the environment).